# Custom JWT token in springboot microservices

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

We have an application that loads information(user specific) from the external system upon successful authentication, to avoid round trips to the external system for each api call,  we are planning create a custom JWT token with user specific information for the first time user authenticated, then the token is send to user in each response header using http interceptor and in the front-end we are including the custom token in every request along with authorization token. Is this correct approach? Do you have any alternative suggestions?

I have looked into other distributed caching techniques like redis but not so appealing for a small usecase. Our payload length does not exceed 4 to 5K hence inclined towards the JWT option

Answer (score 0):

it is ok to include user information that allows you to handle the user authorization inside the access token. Just beware of the privacy implication and perhaps not include personal information like social security number or date-of-birth or other identifiable information.

Also, make sure the token size does not get to big. The other option is to lookup and cache the user information in the API's when it receives a new access token.

Some systems including ASP.NET Core do store the token inside the session cookie in an encrypted form, so that the end user can't see or access the stored tokens.

If you are developing a SPA application, the using the [BFF pattern](https://blog.bitsrc.io/bff-pattern-backend-for-frontend-an-introduction-e4fa965128bf) is one approach.